# Flink Kafka SQL set 'auto.offset.reset'

Tags: apache-flink

I'm not able to set `auto.offset.reset` to latest while using `group-offsets` as scan startup mode. I have tried with properties.* as mentioned in the doc - https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#start-reading-position, but still Kafka consumer group created with `auto.offset.reset`=none(verified in Flink logs) and job fail with error: `Undefined offset with no reset policy for partitions: ....`

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int, order_time timestamp(3),WATERMARK FOR order_time AS order_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND )
WITH (
       'connector' = 'kafka',
       'topic' = 'test_topic',
       'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
       'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
       'format' = 'avro-confluent',
       'scan.startup.mode' = 'group-offsets',
       'properties.auto.offset.reset' = 'latest',
       'avro-confluent.url' = 'http://localhost:8081'
  )
```

Flink version: 1.14.0.

StackTrace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.NoOffsetForPartitionException: Undefined offset with no reset policy for partitions: [test_topic-11]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.resetInitializingPositions(SubscriptionState.java:683)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateFetchPositions(KafkaConsumer.java:2420)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.position(KafkaConsumer.java:1750)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.position(KafkaConsumer.java:1709)
at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaPartitionSplitReader.removeEmptySplits(KafkaPartitionSplitReader.java:375)
at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaPartitionSplitReader.handleSplitsChanges(KafkaPartitionSplitReader.java:260)
at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.AddSplitsTask.run(AddSplitsTask.java:51)
at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:142)
... 6 more
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have `properties.auto.offset.reset` defined in your definition, but such property doesn't exist in the documentation. What happens if you remove that?</strike>

Besides that, I'm wondering if you're also suffering from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24697

Edit: I've misread, `properties` key get forwarded. But I'm wondering what you expect if you set that value to `latest` while specifying `group-offsets` for the `scan.startup.mode`.

Comment: The error occurs in case we have a new Kafka consumer group. Although in the case of  `group-offsets`, consumers should starts with committed  offset of a consumer group, but I think Kafka uses  `auto.offset.reset` parameter in case no committed offset can be found, and hence the error

Comment: If a consumer group already exist with `group.id`, this error won't occur

Comment: If that's the case then it's indeed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24697 that's affecting you too.